# When connecting Tableau to BigQuery, Google always asks for "allow" access

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

This is very annoying, but every time I connect Tableau to BigQuery, Google always asks if I want to allow Tableau access to a my Google Account.  When I click on Account Permissions in Google (https://myaccount.google.com/permissions), Tableau has access and has had it for months, however EVERY SINGLE ITME I connect Tableau to BQ, I get asked this same question.  How do I prevent this window from ever occurring again?

[image]

Comment: Are you following the instructions at http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_googlebigquery.html to connect Tableau to BigQuery?

Comment: Is your Google account your personal gmail account or corporate email account under G-Suite?

Comment: @JL-HN Corp accnt.  I can connect fine, it works, it just asks me this excess question every time.

Comment: It sounds to me like Tableau might not be [refreshing the OAuth2 access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) while you are not using the application. If that is the case, this is something that Tableau would need to opt to support. I think your best course of action for this issue is to contact Tableau's support.